# Update or Insert Multiple Rows into a Table in DB2

Tags: db2, insert-update, upsert, db2-luw

I have a table with 3 columns (ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION). 'ID' is the PRIMARY key. 
As the following query in MySQL to insert/update **two** rows, I want to write a query for DB2 database table.

```
INSERT INTO <Table name> (ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION) VALUES(?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE NAME = VALUES(NAME), DESCRIPTION = VALUES(DESCRIPTION);
```

I tried to modify the following MERGE INTO query to insert/update two rows into the table in DB2 database, but I failed.

```
MERGE INTO <Table name> USING "SYSIBM".DUAL ON (ID= ?)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET NAME= ? , DESCRIPTION= ? 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION) VALUES (?, ?, ?);
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.MYTAB (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(10), DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(20)) 
WITH REPLACE ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS NOT LOGGED
@

BEGIN
  DECLARE V_ID1   INT         DEFAULT 1; 
  DECLARE V_NAME1 VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 'NAME1'; 
  DECLARE V_DESC1 VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT 'DESC1'; 
  DECLARE V_ID2   INT         DEFAULT 2; 
  DECLARE V_NAME2 VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 'NAME2'; 
  DECLARE V_DESC2 VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT 'DESC2'; 

  PREPARE S1 FROM '
  MERGE INTO SESSION.MYTAB T USING 
  (
  VALUES
    (CAST(? AS INT), CAST(? AS VARCHAR(10)), CAST(? AS VARCHAR(20)))
  , (CAST(? AS INT), CAST(? AS VARCHAR(10)), CAST(? AS VARCHAR(20)))
  ) S (ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION) ON T.ID = S.ID
  WHEN     MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET NAME = S.NAME, DESCRIPTION = S.DESCRIPTION 
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION) VALUES (S.ID, S.NAME, S.DESCRIPTION)
  ';

  EXECUTE S1 USING 
    V_ID1, V_NAME1, V_DESC1
  , V_ID2, V_NAME2, V_DESC2;
END
@

SELECT * FROM SESSION.MYTAB
@
```